# WPF MVVM How read property value, binded to another element, in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to do a simple thing, I've searching around the web but I've not found a solution. I use ColorPicker from Wpf Toolkit library, the property **SelectedColor** is binded to an element Label on **Foreground** Property.
It works correctly, when I change color from color picker the label changes its color, but I can't find a way to get the selected color in my viewmodel.
Normally I used to bind my property to viewmodel and manage it on onPropertyChanged event, but how can I do in this situation?

**XAML**

```
<Label Name="LabelMeasureValue1" Content="{Binding TrendingMeasure1Value}" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyleBold}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
<wpfTool:ColorPicker Name="ColorPick1" DisplayColorAndName="True" ShowStandardColors="False" AvailableColors="{Binding ColorItems}" SelectedColor="{Binding ElementName=LabelMeasureValue1, Path=Foreground, Converter={StaticResource brushColorConv}}" Tag="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBoxMeasure1}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30">
    <wpfTool:ColorPicker.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource enblTrendConv}">
            <Binding Path="Device.EsitoUltimaLettura" />
            <Binding Path="IsGraphRunning" Converter="{StaticResource invBoolValueConv}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </wpfTool:ColorPicker.IsEnabled>
</wpfTool:ColorPicker>
```

Comment: Why not bind them both to the same property in VM?

Comment: Thanks it works, but is the only solution? Or it is possible get it works with my config?

Comment: I don't really see a reason to complicate things. In your setup you'd want to bind ColorPicker both to VM property and to Label value at the same time which is impossible. You can still return value to VM from selection change event handler of ColorPicker if you want to keep this setup.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your hint.